# Case Syntax - Subtraction of 2 values gives incorrect number

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am working on this assignment:

[image]

The code that I wrote based on this is:

```
SELECT Number1, Number2, MathOperation, Result = CASE
WHEN MathOperation = 'Addition' THEN Number1 + Number2
WHEN MathOperation = 'Substraction' THEN Number1 - Number2
WHEN MathOperation = 'Multiplication' THEN Number1 * Number2
ELSE Number1 / Number2
END
FROM @Math;
```

The Subtraction Result (**Second WHEN**) is the same as the Division Result (**ELSE**), which is not correct. 
I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. Could you please help?

Comment: Maybe because you've misspelled Subtraction?

Comment: Yes, that was the case for this one. It's always the simple mistakes that are harder to spot on the first try. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving the correct result.

Your query is not working properly/behaving differently and producing the wrong result, it might be because the data in the table `Subtraction` and the value in the case statement `Substraction` is different.

```
create table Math(id int identity(1, 1) primary key
, Number1 decimal(16, 2)
, Number2 decimal(16, 2)
, MathOperation NVARCHAR(100))

insert into Math values
  (128, 48, 'Addition')
, (128, 48, 'Substraction')
, (128, 48, 'Multiplication')
, (128, 48, 'Division')

SELECT Number1
    ,Number2
    ,MathOperation
    ,Result = CASE 
        WHEN MathOperation = 'Addition'
            THEN Number1 + Number2
        WHEN MathOperation = 'Substraction'
            THEN Number1 - Number2
        WHEN MathOperation = 'Multiplication'
            THEN Number1 * Number2
        ELSE Number1 / Number2
        END
FROM Math
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ea388b0aac08598bd04c617ac3b1c89)

Comment: Happy to hear that it's correct. Thank you :) I think I found out where the issues was - Language Barrier problem - I wrote Subtraction as Substraction. but after I corrected it worked fine.

Comment: This is probably just a typo problem, misspelling `Subtraction` for `Substraction`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It maybe but I have tried to check with practically and is working fine.